# An unexpected error while writing the code

Tags: android, windows, kotlin, encoding

[image: 1]

what's worng?

I didn't expect that error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your Map has values that Doubles and a value that is an Int. Therefore, the type of the Map's values is the common supertype Number. When you retrieve something from the Map, it will be known to the compiler and your code as the type Number, not Double or Int.

There is no `div` function for Number. It's not a very useful interface. Math operations can only be done with specific types of numbers, because this information is necessary to determine how the math operation will be performed and what kind of number will be the result. Ints and Doubles work very differently in terms of how they are stored in memory and how mathematical operations are done on them.

I am guessing you meant for all your values to be Doubles, so you should use `1.0` instead of `1` when declaring the value in your `mapOf()` call.